# Retrieve the PFFile saved in parse and play using MPPlayerViewController ? I have tried this code but was unsuccessful to play in the player.

Tags: ios, parse-platform, video-streaming

-(void)shouldPlayVideo{
   // You can download the data for the video through the SDK, or you can use the URL of the video stored on Parse.

```
   // Say you have a Class on Parse called MyClass, that has a column of type File named MyFile:

    // assuming you've queried MyClass and have an object, we'll call it object
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPPhotoClassKey];

[query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Video"];
```

// [query whereKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

```
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

NSArray *ary = [query findObjects];

NSLog(@"ary is %@",ary);

for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {


    PFObject *obj = [ary objectAtIndex:i];

    PFFile *theFile = obj[@"image"];

    NSLog(@"%@",theFile.url);
```

//     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theFile.url];

```
    // the .url property contains the URL for the file (video or otherwise)..
// If you want to download the data:
[theFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // data contains the full file... this block will run when it is downloaded.
    // use it inside this block.

    NSString *yourstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:yourstring];
    NSLog(@"url of video file is %@",url);

    MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [theMovie.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 200)];
    //    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:theMovie.view];

   }];
```

}
}